# Form not submitting when pressing enter, even with a submit button

Tags: html, css

As in the title, if I press enter my form is not submitted by default.
I would prefer don't add js code, but i cannot explain  but I can not explain what's wrong with it. Any suggestions?
I also tried to change my button in a input without results.
If I click on the sign in button the form works.

//
instead of a " # " obviously there is a link to another html page. If I click on the button all works, i want that when a user insert his email and his password he can log in pressing enter

```html
<div class="login-box" style="display:block">
  <div class="form-header" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">
    <div class="content-form">
      <form action="#" id="login-form" class="login-form smart-form client-form text-center">
        <div class="login-input">
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" autocomplete='off' id="username" name="email" value="" tabindex="1" required><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="fa fa-user txt-color-teal"></i> Please enter
                                                                                          your email
                                                                                          address/username</b>
        </div>
        <div class="login-input" style="margin-top:20px;">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete='off' id="password" name="password" value="" tabindex="2">
          <i class="fa-lg fa-fw fa fa-lock"></i>
          <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="fa fa-lock txt-color-teal"></i> Enter your
                                                                                          password</b>
          <div class="note"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="login-input hidden" style="margin-top:20px;text-align:right;">
          <input class="checkbox form-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="remember" checked="checked" id="check" />
          <label class="form-checkbox-label" for="check">Stay signed in</label>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:30px;">
          <button id="loginButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-login" tabindex="3">login</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your form as an `action` of `#`: that means the form will submit to the same page it is on. Does the page itself has any server-side logic to handle form submission? Otherwise you need to point the `action` of the form to a proper resource on your server that handles the logging in process.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me when I click enter in a text field. Is your question about submitting the form when not being focues on an input element?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/uMACoEs.png —The form submits when I test it

Comment: check the passed action first, correct that and if there is still error, raise the query here

Comment: can you tell us what is your expected result?

Comment: instead of a " # " obviously there is a link to another html page. If I click on the button all works, i want that when a user insert his email and his password he can log in pressing enter

Answer (score -2):

for submitting form you need to add function than send a from to server, like this:

```
<form action="sendForm()" id="login-form"...>
```

Comment: No. There is absolutely no need to involve JavaScript to submit a form … and that's not a valid way to include JavaScript anyway.